# iGroup Presence Questionnaire (IPQ) – SPSS Spider / Radar Chart

Tags: spss

I find this Spider/Radar Chart on the IPQ side really good: http://www.igroup.org/pq/ipq/data.php

[Picture of the Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsisH.png)

But how is it done in SPSS? Because I can’t find any Radar Chart in the options.

I computed already this means:

```
compute sp2u = -1 * sp2 + 6.
execute.

compute inv3u = -1 * inv3 + 6.
execute.

compute real1u = -1 * real1 + 6.
execute.

compute sp = mean(sp1, sp2u, sp3, sp4, sp5).
compute inv = mean(inv1, inv2, inv3u, inv4).
compute real = mean(real1u, real2, real3, real4).
execute.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the chart referenced was not produced with SPSS. I don't believe that exact chart could be produced in SPSS. The closest thing I know of would be to edit GPL syntax for a 3-D scatterplot to use lines instead of points to draw a triangular shape, like the following example, but there's a lot in the chart you want that's not here.

```
DATA LIST LIST / x y z.
BEGIN DATA.
0 0 10
0 10 0 
10 0 0
END DATA.

GGRAPH 
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=x y z
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE
  /FITLINE TOTAL=NO.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: x=col(source(s), name("x"))
  DATA: y=col(source(s), name("y"))
  DATA: z=col(source(s), name("z"))
  COORD: rect(dim(1,2,3))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("z"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("x"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(3), label("y"))
  GUIDE: text.title(label("Whatever Title You Want"))
  ELEMENT: line(position(z*x*y))
END GPL.
```